# CrashLoopBackOff (Mongo in Docker/Kubernetes) - Failed to start up WiredTiger under any compatibility version

Tags: mongodb, docker, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I'm suddenly facing some issues in my Kubernetes application (with no event to explain it). The application has been working properly during one year but now I'm getting a CrashLoopBackOff status.

---

**IMPORTANT UPDATE:**

I cannot update the Mongo replication controller in GKE, because when I commit the changes in mongo.yml (from GIT) all workloads update except mongo-controller (which is down).

In GKE in Workloads/Mongo-controller/Managed pods I can see that the "Created on" date is some days ago when the app was up. The rest of pods are updating with my commits. I don't want to delete the Mongo pod, because I suppose that we'd lost the database info/content. (The developer who created the cluster pipeline didn't schedule a backup).

---

**Database**: MongoDB (latest, not sure what was the one running properly)
**OS**: Pod running on Ubuntu 18.04
**CLuster**: Google Cloud Kubernetes Engines (a.k.a GKE)

**Kubectl get pods**

```
mongo-controller-dgkkg 0/1 CrashLoopBackOff 1199 4d6h
```

**Logs of Mongo POD**

Automatically disabling TLS 1.0, to force-enable TLS 1.0 specify --sslDisabledProtocols 'none'

No TransportLayer configured during NetworkInterface startup"}

Implicit TCP FastOpen unavailable. If TCP FastOpen is required, set tcpFastOpenServer, tcpFastOpenClient, and tcpFastOpenQueueSize.

MongoDB starting","attr":{"pid":1,"port":27017,"dbPath":"/data/db","architecture":"64-bit","host":"mongo-controller-dgkkg"}

Build Info","attr":{"buildInfo":{"version":"4.4.1","gitVersion":"ad91a93a5a31e175f5cbf8c69561e788bbc55ce1","openSSLVersion":"OpenSSL 1.1.1 11 Sep 2018","modules":[],"allocator":"tcmalloc","environment":{"distmod":"ubuntu1804","distarch":"x86_64","target_arch":"x86_64"}}}

Operating System","attr":{"os":{"name":"Ubuntu","version":"18.04"}}

Options set by command line","attr":{"options":{"net":{"bindIp":"*"}}}

Storage engine to use detected by data files","attr":{"dbpath":"/data/db","storageEngine":"wiredTiger"}

Using the XFS filesystem is strongly recommended with the WiredTiger storage engine. See [http://dochub.mongodb.org/core/prodnotes-filesystem","tags":["startupWarnings"]](http://dochub.mongodb.org/core/prodnotes-filesystem%22,%22tags%22:%5B%22startupWarnings%22%5D)

Opening WiredTiger","attr":{"config":"create,cache_size=1336M,session_max=33000,eviction=(threads_min=4,threads_max=4),config_base=false,statistics=(fast),log=(enabled=true,archive=true,path=journal,compressor=snappy),file_manager=(close_idle_time=100000,close_scan_interval=10,close_handle_minimum=250),statistics_log=(wait=0),verbose=[recovery_progress,checkpoint_progress,compact_progress]

***Failed to start up WiredTiger under any compatibility version. This may be due to an unsupported upgrade or downgrade.***

Terminating.","attr":{"reason":"95: Operation not supported"}}

Fatal assertion","attr":{"msgid":28595,"file":"src/mongo/db/storage/wiredtiger/wiredtiger_kv_engine.cpp","line":1101}}

\n\n***aborting after fassert() failure\n\n

**My Mongo.yml:**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mongo
  namespace: $KUBE_NAMESPACE-$CI_ENVIRONMENT_SLUG
  labels:
    name: mongo
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 27017
      targetPort: 27017
  selector:
    name: mongo
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ReplicationController
metadata:
  name: mongo-controller
  namespace: $KUBE_NAMESPACE-$CI_ENVIRONMENT_SLUG
  labels:
    name: mongo
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        name: mongo
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: mongo
        name: mongo
        ports:
        - name: mongo
          containerPort: 27017
          hostPort: 27017
        volumeMounts:
            - name: mongo-persistent-storage
              mountPath: /data/db
      volumes:
        - name: mongo-persistent-storage
          gcePersistentDisk:
            pdName: mongo-disk-$CI_ENVIRONMENT_SLUG
            fsType: ext4
```

PD: Maybe I should update my ReplicationController to Deployment (recommended), but being a database container we always configure it in that way. However I tried that, and nothing changed.

Comment: Maybe you mongo image was update because you aren't specifying a tag, it means you are always pulling the latest version. Do you know the stable version you are runnig before?

Comment: What's the best practice to specify the tag version of Mongo? Thank

Comment: I have the same issue, but in my case it just installed on a new server. I'm testing MongoDb on ARM and does not start because this message.

Comment: @AlexAcc, [Here](https://hub.docker.com/_/mongo?tab=description) you can find all tags. Do you know what version the version that was working?

Answer (score 1):

I solved this issue editing the Replication Controller online from the Google Cloud Console.

Access to: "Kubernetes Engine" > "Workload" > "mongo-controller" > "Managed pods" > "mongo-controller-XXXXX"

...and press EDIT button (in the top navbar). You can edit the configuration online in real time. I simply specified the Mongo version (4.2.10) in the image, and  everything woked as expected.

```
    spec:
      replicas: 1
      selector:
        name: mongo
      template:
        metadata:
          creationTimestamp: null
          labels:
            name: mongo
        spec:
          containers:
          - image: mongo: 4.2.10

          (...)
```