# How to apply configuration to a down Mongo pod in Kubernetes cluster?

Tags: mongodb, docker, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I have a running cluster in Kubernetes (Google Cloud), with 2 pods for 2 frontend apps (Angular), 1 pod backend app (NodeJS) and 1 pod for Mongo DB (currently Down)

In the last code update from git Mongo version updated unintencionally, image tag was not specified in Replication Controller, so it took the latest. This version seems not work.

I get *CrashLoopBackOff* error in Kubernetes, and the details are:

```
Failed to start up WiredTiger under any compatibility version. This may be due to an unsupported upgrade or downgrade."}
```

I have updated the Replication Controller specifying a Mongo version, but when I commit/push the change, workload in Google Cloud is not updating because it's down. The date of last "Created on" is some days ago, not now (see attached images if it's not clear what I'm trying to explain).

---

**My 2 biggest doubts are:**

- How to force the (re)start of the Mongo Pod (with the added tag specifying the version), in order to fix the down pod issue?
- How could I recover the data of the Mongo database in GKE, in order to migrate it quickly?

---

**New Mongo.yaml**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mongo
  namespace: sgw-production
  labels:
    name: mongo
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 27017
      targetPort: 27017
  selector:
    name: mongo
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ReplicationController
metadata:
  name: mongo-controller
  namespace: sgw-production
  labels:
    name: mongo
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        name: mongo
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: mongo:4.2.10
        name: mongo
        ports:
        - name: mongo
          containerPort: 27017
          hostPort: 27017
        volumeMounts:
            - name: mongo-persistent-storage
              mountPath: /data/db
      volumes:
        - name: mongo-persistent-storage
          gcePersistentDisk:
            pdName: mongo-disk-$CI_ENVIRONMENT_SLUG
            fsType: ext4
```

Comment: Please do not edit answers into questions. Instead please create an answer. You might have noticed that you have two questions in one and could not answer both yet. That is the reason why questions can get closed if they do not focus on one question. So you might consider separating one of the two into a dedicated second question, allowing yourself to answer one of the two.

Comment: Have you tried to make a snapshot/image out of your `mongo-disk-$CI_ENVIRONMENT_SLUG` disk for backup purposes? After that you can create new disk (from earlier created snapshot/image) and mount it as `PVC` to your  new `Pod` running mongo. Is there any specific reason that you are using `ReplicationController` instead of a `Deployment` or a `StatefulSet`?

Answer (score 0):

I answered my own question here with the solution to this issue (copy/paste below):

[CrashLoopBackOff (Mongo in Docker/Kubernetes) - Failed to start up WiredTiger under any compatibility version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64458588/crashloopbackoff-mongo-in-docker-kubernetes-failed-to-start-up-wiredtiger-un/64750503#64750503)

I solved this issue editing the Replication Controller online from the Google Cloud Console.

Access to: "Kubernetes Engine" > "Workload" > "mongo-controller" > "Managed pods" > "mongo-controller-XXXXX"

...and press EDIT button (in the top navbar). You can edit the configuration online in real time. I simply specified the Mongo version (4.2.10) in the image, and  everything woked as expected.

```
    spec:
      replicas: 1
      selector:
        name: mongo
      template:
        metadata:
          creationTimestamp: null
          labels:
            name: mongo
        spec:
          containers:
          - image: mongo: 4.2.10

          (...)
```